# XML file as input

Tags: python, lxml

I have the following line of code: `xml = BytesIO("<A><B>some text</B></A>")` for the file named `test.xml`.

But I would like to have something like `xml = "/home/user1/test.xml"`

How can I use the file location instread of having to put the file content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will read in the contents of the file into a string, and pass it into the class instantiator for **BytesIO**

```
xml = BytesIO(open("/home/user1/test.xml").read())
```

Answer (score 1):

Exactly like you have.  `lxml.etree.parse()` accepts a string filename and will read the file for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
xml = open('/home/user1/test.xml', 'rb').read()
```